# Trying to copy a file inside the deployed WAR file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to copy a file inside a [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29) file, but it gives an exception. The code is:

```
multipartfile.transferto("destination"+multipartfile.getOriginalName());
```

Here destination is `D:/warFileName.war`. It works fine with any folder, but with a WAR file it throws an exception at run time.

Comment: What is the exception? Does your application allow war files to be uploaded(?)

Comment: So you're appending a file to a deployed war file? This seems like a bad idea. I know Tomcat can actually detect file changes and redeploy--probably not what you want. What are you *really* trying to accomplish, here?

Comment: Yes I am trying to append any new file for example abc.txt inside the deployed war file so that I need not to recreate the war. I am able to transfer the abc.txt inside some folder on my machine but not inside the war file.